# Javascript - setInterval remains executing when declaration is removed

Tags: javascript, variables, global, setinterval

I've got a problem with `setInterval` function. I've got an HTML page that loads content dynamically. The content is loaded via `AJAX Post Request` against a PHP Script that contains the target HTML content that is being loaded into an HTML `div`. Also a Javascript script is loaded and executed when the content is loaded dynamically. That `script` calls `setInterval` function and it executes forever. The problem comes when I load new content dynamically, I want `setInterval` function to stop because content that was being affected by `setInterval` is removed, but It continues executing, and throws error due to elements don't exist. It's obvious because the function is loaded in memory and the page ins't reloaded, so memory isn't flushed.

I need to clear the interval when loading new content (this also happens if I reload the new content: old `setInterval` still executes and new also does).

This is a simple example of the script being dynamically loaded:

```
//Autoload Array for each Grid
var GRID_autoLoad = new Array();

function Grid_autoLoad(grid_id){

   //This doesn't work! A new instance of the variable is created everytime
   if(GRID_autoLoad[grid_id] !== undefined ) {
      clearInterval(GRID_autoLoad[grid_id]);
   }

   GRID_autoLoad[grid_id] = setInterval(function(){
       Grid_load(grid_id);
   }, 5000);
}

function Grid_init(grid_id){
    Grid_load(grid_id);
    Grid_autoLoad(grid_id);
}
```

I'm not able to check if the variable is already defined and clear the previous interval because a new instance of the variable is created when reloading the content! How can I unset `setInterval` function?

Comment: You have to call `clearInterval` with the value returned from `setInterval`. So you'll need to store that return value persistently somewhere and access it from the new fragment. There are crude ways (global variables) and cleaner ways (create a module with an API), but fundamentally that's what has to happen.

Comment: if your `GRID_autoLoad ` variable is remvoed when you load the new content look into `sessionStorage` to persist it on the client whilst the window is open. Just be aware of the fact all values in `session/localStorage` are strings. Also please use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. Baby unicorns will die if you use `new Array()`

Comment: @ste2425 It worked perfectly with `localStorage`. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, you can answer your own questions if you have a solution and mark it as correct. May be of help to others.